# How to fix appending a timestamp when moving a folder on a remote server to a new location on the remote server?

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I am trying to run a batch script on my local machine that will take care of some log archiving on some servers. I can access the servers via file explorer "\SERVERNAME\C$\SOME FOLDER." When I attempt to xcopy from the source to the destination locally and append a timestamp its like the TIMESTAMP variable doesn't store my date/time concatenation.

This is for windows 2012r2 servers, I've tried to append just the date\time to the end which works fine, however, its not the desired format I am looking for and it starts nesting the directory with the date but no time and it looks like a mess. :(

I've also tried to use the wmic however this is the first time I am writing a batch file to automate some tasks so all this has been a great learning experience.

I've tried to `echo %TIMESTAMP%` and nothing returns? I've even tried to add the concatenation `(%CUR_YYYY%%CUR_MM%%CUR_DD%-%CUR_HH%%CUR_NN%%CUR_SS%)` directly to the file directory and its doesn't work :(

```
REM Check to see if a service on the machine is stopped (it is always stopped by the time it gets here) before we move the files from the logging directory to a new one.
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc \\REMOTESERVER query "SOME SERVICE NAME" ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
  if /I "%%H" == "STOPPED" (
    REM substring the date and time and then concat it together at the end to make the desired timestamp variable
      set CUR_YYYY = %date:~10,4%
      set CUR_MM = %date:~4,2%
      set CUR_DD = %date:~7,2%
      set CUR_HH = %time:~0,2%
      set CUR_NN = %time:~3,2%
      set CUR_SS = %time:~6,2%
      set CUR_MS = %time:~9,2%
      set TIMESTAMP = %CUR_YYYY%%CUR_MM%%CUR_DD%-%CUR_HH%%CUR_NN%%CUR_SS%

    REM copy files from the servers source directory and then move the files to a newly created logging folder with a timestamp appened at the end
    echo d | xcopy /f /y "\\REMOTE SERVER\src" "\\REMOTE SERVER\dest\Logging_%TIMESTAMP%" /E /I
    REM delete the contents of the servers source directory to keep things nice and clean
    pushd \\REMOTE SERVER\src && del . /F /Q popd
  )
)
```

The expected result would look like:
SourceFolder on the server will be there but empty
DestinationFolder will have a new Logging folder created Logging_20190325010101 and within the newly created logging folder all the contents from the SourceFolder should be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of the whitespace before and after your `=` in your set commands, also, You need `delayedexpansion` in the codeblock with changing variables, and there is a better way to get rid of the colons and comma.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM Check to see if a service on the machine is stopped (it is always stopped by the time it gets here) before we move the files from the logging directory to a new one.
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc \\REMOTESERVER query "SOME SERVICE NAME" ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
  if /I "%%H" == "STOPPED" (
REM substring the date and time and then concat it together at the end to make the desired timestamp variable
  set "CUR_YYYY=%date:~10,4%"
  set "CUR_MM=%date:~4,2%"
  set "CUR_DD=%date:~7,2%"
  set "mytime=!time::=!"
  set "mytime=!mytime:,=!"
  set "TIMESTAMP=!CUR_YYYY!!CUR_MM!!CUR_DD!-!mytime!"

REM copy files from the servers source directory and then move the files to a newly created logging folder with a timestamp appened at the end
echo d | xcopy /f /y "\\REMOTE SERVER\src" "\\REMOTE SERVER\dest\Logging_!TIMESTAMP!" /E /I
REM delete the contents of the servers source directory to keep things nice and clean
pushd \\REMOTE SERVER\src && del . /F /Q popd
 )
)
```

To explain your issue however, when you set a variable, the whitespace comes as part of the variable.. So:

```
set variable = value
```

Will result in a variable with a trailing space `%variable %` and a value with a leading space `<space>value` So we always get rid of the whitespace and best to use double quotes to eliminate possible whitespace after the value. for instance:

```
set "variable=value"
```

which will create `%variable%` and `value`

Comment: Can you just briefly explain why you use % for the date but not for time? I see Rojo mentions ! Is used when want to delay expansion? Thanks for the your help in advance.

Comment: You can use `!` for date as well, I did not update everything in the answer though... but I was focusing on showing you how expansion works on the time variable.

Answer (score 0):

Within parenthetical code blocks you have to delay expansion when retrieving variable values in the same block in which they were set.  For example:

```js
(
    set "test=1"
    echo [%test%]
)
```

... would echo "[]" because `%test%` was *retrieved* within the same parenthetical code block in which it was *set*.  At the time `%test%` is evaluated, it has no value.  You must delay expansion either by using `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` or by using `call echo [%%test%%]` (or `cmd /c` or similar).  When using `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`, you delay expansion by using `!` instead of `%` to denote variables.  See `setlocal /?` and `set /?` in a cmd console for more information -- particularly the section of `set /?` that begins "Finally, support for delayed environment variable expansion has been added."

Also, it's much simpler and more locale agnostic to compose your timestamp using `wmic os get localdatetime`.  Example:

```js
for /f "delims=." %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /value ^| find "="') do set "%%~I"
echo %localdatetime%
```

That should result in `%localdatetime%` containing the current numeric value of YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.